# Can't fgets() a 1 gig file?

Tags: php

Code:

```
$filename = 'Master_List_DeDuped.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");

while (false !== ($line = fgets($fp))) {

    echo $line;
    die(); // For Debugging only
}

fclose($fp);
```

The resulting error:

`Warning: fgets(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in /home3/public_html/index.php on line 288`

Line 288 is the while statement. The same commands work fine with a smaller file. My file is about 1.1 gigs. Is it just a file size limitation?

Edit: I've tried adding the length parameter to fgets, but the same error shows. https://www.php.net/fgets

Comment: What happens if you insert `if (!$fp) die("Could not open file");` right after the `fopen` line?

Comment: Nothing. Same error as before. I am making progress using the sample listed at php.net though.

Comment: Have you tried stream_get_line instead? The line endings will not be included using that function.

Comment: No. Not sure what I was doing wrong, but I solved it myself by using the code in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code a bit based on the example at php.net https://www.php.net/fgets . The code that works is:

```
$filename = 'Master_List_DeDuped.csv';
$fp = @fopen($filename, "r");
if ($fp) {
    while (($line = fgets($fp, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $line;
        die(); // For Debugging only
    }
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: there is a post here which could be useful suggesting stream_get_line as well http://us1.php.net/fgets by Leigh Purdie

Comment: Thank you! Anders above mentioned that in a comment, but I only saw it after I solved my own problem. I'm going to test `stream_get_line` still to see if it works any more smoothly. It appears to be around 5x faster in the sample.